# CSS: Div is Smaller Than Object

Tags: html, css, browser, png, jpeg

I have tried everything I can think of, like: *overflow*, *box-sizing*, *messing with divs* in the html, *hard-coding div width*, etc. Yet nothing is working and I'm not seeing any inherited characteristics that need overriding for any of these to work.

This is causing a problem where my image has a massive amount of whitespace around it and I can't figure out how to get it to stop (since my code is already working on other pages).

I've tried switching from `.png` to `.jpg` and back, but its been no use.

Any help is appreciated.

(*Border-radius* also doesn't work due to this, which was sort of my first hint it was a div size problem.)

My HTML:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content-header-wrapper">
        <h2>Page Title.</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="title-img"><img src="../Images/headshot.jpg"></div>

    <div class="content-message-wrapper">
        <div class="p1-titlewrap">
            <h3>1st Paragraph Header</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
 .content-wrapper {
    justify-items:center;
    background-color: white;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    font-family: "Ubuntu Condensed", sans-serif;
    height:auto;
}

.content-wrapper .content-header-wrapper {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.content-wrapper .title-img {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    transform: scale(.15,.15);
    box-sizing: content-box; 
}
```

Comment: do want to make the img to occupy the full div(.title-img)?

Comment: First thing I notice is that you are missing two closing (`</div>`) tags. Perhaps that's what's causing it?

Comment: what is the reason you use `transform: scale (.15, .15);` ??

if only to shrink the image size, why not use width - height ??

Comment: Width and height aren't responsive. Transform was. @Amaresh S M, yes I'm trying to make title-img div the size of the image itself so it responds to commands again.

Comment: @RichardYan I'm missing divs because this is only a fragment of the overall page code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adjusting the transform: scale() property in the CSS? or is that not something you wanted to do in the first place?

Comment: Yeah, transform was the only property that would respond to scale the image. Before I did this the image was so large it was causing a page overflow. This made it so the image was centered where I wanted along the x-axis, but now there's massive whitespace around it.

Comment: Turns out that manually re-scaling the image in inkscape and then eliminating the css transform property was the way to go. Didn't know that transform didn't adjust the object footprint, only the object itself. That's good to know. Probably a good thing I don't use this attribute very often...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe set "background-size: cover;" that should fill the entire div with the image. If not why not try and resize the image so that it fills up more space.

Comment: I'll try that. The original image was massive. Like, page-breaking massive. Scaling down was the only thing that could get it to fit in an article-type format.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set image as css property `background` and set `background-size:cover;`. Hope it will help you to solve this problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, this made no difference in the image space issue or the div size issue. May just give-up and try a manual re-scale via inkscape.